# Entity Type Recogition : Finding an Entity's Dominant Type from its Description

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I've been working on a research project. I have a database of Wikipedia descriptions of a large number of entities, including sportspersons, politicians, actors, etc. The aim is to determine the type of entity using the descriptions. I have access to some data with the predicted type of entity which is quite accurate. **This will be my training data.** What I would like to do is train a model to predict the dominant type of entity for rest of the data.

What I've done till now:

- Extracted the first paragraph, H1, H2 headers of Wiki description of the entity.
- Extracted the category list of the entity on the wiki page (The bottom 'Categories' section present on any page [like here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulp_Fiction#mw-normal-catlinks)

Finding the type of entity can be difficult for entities that are associated with two or more concepts, like an ***actor who later became a politician.***

**I want to ask as to how I create a model out of the raw data that I have?** **What are the variables that I should use to train the model?** 
Also are there any Natural Language Processing techniques that can be helpful for this purpose? I know POS taggers can be helpful in this case.

My search over the internet has not been much successful. I've stumbled across research papers and blogs like [this one](https://www.searchtechnologies.com/blog/natural-language-processing-techniques), but none of them have relevant information for this purpose. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT 1:

The input data is the first paragraph of the Wikipedia page of the entity. For example, for [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Franken), my input would be:

Alan Stuart Franken (born May 21, 1951) is an American comedian, writer, producer, author, and politician who served as a United States Senator from Minnesota from 2009 to 2018. He became well known in the 1970s and 1980s as a performer on the television comedy show Saturday Night Live (SNL). After decades as a comedic actor and writer, he became a prominent liberal political activist, hosting The Al Franken Show on Air America Radio.

My extracted information is, the first paragraph of the page, the string of all the 'Categories' (bottom part of the page), and all the headers of the page.

Comment: I would like to help, but I need to know what is your input text and what are the labels you want to predict?

Comment: Thanks! Edited the question. I need to somehow extract Al Franklen's dominant type, actor or politician. For this example it might not be clear, but for some entity with 10 years of acting career and 1 year of being a politician, the output should be 'actor'.

Comment: Ok, it is confusing because you state you want the `type of entity using the descriptions` and in the edit `extracted information is, the string of all the 'Categories'`. Is it only the categories on the pages or also some single individual's name?

Comment: Edited. The input would also contain the first paragraph of the Wikipedia page of the entity.

Comment: I added an answer which tries to take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather you would like to have a classifier which takes text input and predicts from a list of predefined categories.

I am not sure what your level of expertise is, so I will give a high level overview if additional people would like to know about the subject.

Like all NLP tasks which use ML, you are going to have to transform your `textual` domain to a `numerical` domain by a process of `featurization`.

1. Process the text and labels
2. Determine the relevant features
3. Create numerical representation of features
4. Train and Test on a Classifier

## Process the text and labels

the text might have some strange markers or things that need to be modified to make it more "clean". this is standard as a text normalisation step.

then you will have to keep the related categories as labels for the texts.

It will end up being something like the following:

```
For each wiki article:
    Normalise wiki article text
    Save associated categories labels with text for training
```

## Determine the relevant features

Some features you seem to have mentioned are:

1. Dominant field (actor, politician)
2. Header information

Syntactic information (POS Tags) are local (token level), but can be used to extract specific features such as if words are proper nouns or not.

## Create numerical representation of features

Luckily, there are ways of doing auto-encoding, such as doc2vec, which can make a document vector from the text. Then you can add additional bespoke features that seem relevant.

You will then have a vector representation of features relevant to this text as well as the labels (categories).

This will become your training data.

## Train and Test on a Classifier

Now train and test on a classifier of your choice.

Your data is one-to-many as you will try to predict many labels.

Try something simple just to seem if things work as you expect.

You should test your results with a cross validation routine such as k-fold validation using standard metrics (Precision, Recall, F1)

## Clarification

Just to help clarify, This task is not really a named entity recognition task. It is a kind of multi-label classification task, where the labels are the categories defined on the wikipedia pages.

Named Entity Recognition is finding meaningful named entities in a document such as people, places. Usually something noun-like. This is usually done on a token level whereas your task is on a document level it seems.